# is the command search part of another package apt-get cannot find it

Tags: apt, grub2, package-management

new challange trying to follow the first comment below.

@ubvan1   Have I installed the wrong grub?

there is no search command listed in `grub> help`
Tried the following and got Unrecognized command

```
grub> search --name sb2 root 
search --name sb2 root 

Error 27: Unrecognized command
grub> search
search

Error 27: Unrecognized command
grub>
```

This is my first time dealing with fixing grub2 at the command line. 
I did not even know grub was more than a file and included it's own command line.

You say that the commands are in a cfg file. which I took to be a config file which is not an exicutable in its self but used by an exicutable which I assumed would be grub.

Is grub.cfg an exicutable? If so, do I run it from

```
lubuntu@lubuntu:~
```

or from

```
grub>
```

and how?

I know there are files in /EFI/ubuntu/ but I seem to be in the wrong root because when I enter

```
lubuntu@lubuntu:/$ cd /EFI/ubuntu/
bash: cd: /EFI/ubuntu/: No such file or directory
lubuntu@lubuntu:/$
```

I have looked around and searched for How do I get from /sdax to /sday from the command line?
I am lost there too. and keep getting the following

```
lubuntu@lubuntu:/$ cd /EFI/ubuntu/
bash: cd: /EFI/ubuntu/: No such file or directory
lubuntu@lubuntu:/$ 

lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ grub
The program 'grub' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install grub
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo apt install grub
```

---

Original entry

I am trying desperately to follow ubfan1's 
Re: Boot Device Not Found (3F0) Pavilion 23 All In One
Instructions excep I cannot use search.fs_uuid because it is not on the current Ubuntu or Lubuntu live disks.

The specific instructions are:
    And also under the /EFI/ubuntu you will need a grub.cfg file. You may use a stub like the below to pull in the full grub.cfg from /boot/grub
    (Assuming the root is on partition 8 below, change for your situation)

```
search.fs_uuid Your-uuid-here root hd0,gpt8
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

What I am entering in Terminal and the replies:

```
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ search.fs_uuid Your-uuid-here root hd0,gpt8 -h
search.fs_uuid: command not found
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install search
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package search
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$
```

The same for `search.fs_uuid`

Research in the forums and Docs indicate they are valid commands.

the original problem is 
Mount /sys on root/sys Failed No file
No init found Try passing init= (boot arg)

I have created the directories on sb2 [When I removed Windows 8 sb1 became unaccessable, so Lumbutu put the grub2 files on sb2. At least that is where I found them]

It looks like all I have to do is exicute

```
search.fs_uuid Your-uuid-here root hd0,gpt8
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

from `lubuntu@lubuntu:~$` and mount /sys on root/sys.

should succeed Correct?

Comment: Those commands, search.fs_uuid.... should be in the /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg file.  You may type them in at the grub menu prompt by typing "e" to edit, type in commands with your UUID, and then control X to boot (instructions at bottom of screen).

Comment: ... see https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/search.html#search

Comment: Have I installed the wrong grub?

Comment: I need more information but unlike the forum anything i put in keeps getting kicked out because its 252 characters too long, I try editing and get refused because I cannot edit in less than 5 minutes

Comment: know there are files in sda2/EFI/ubuntu/ but I seem to be in the wrong root because when I enter
lubuntu@lubuntu:/$ cd /EFI/ubuntu/
I'm getting this.
bash: cd: /EFI/ubuntu/: No such file or directory
I do not know how to get back to that partition from where ever I am.

Comment: I was trying to use these commands in Lubuntu terminal instead of as you indicate the Grub terminal. I did not get that "should be in the /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg file" that Grub even had a terminal until I started getting the Grub> prompts and the little instruction about how to use <tab>. Your inclusion of "grub menu prompt . . ." cleared that up. If it was there before I missed it. Thank you. and thank you for your patience.